# Why is my C# code syntax highlighted in the comment section

Tags: support

I posted an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25650081/380384 and noticed that words like `select` or `go` in my comments are highlighted blue.

Shouldn't the syntax highlighter make all comments *gray* or something for better readability? Is this an issue with my client (I am on Chrome) or with the website?

Comment: probably because the Q is tagged VB.Net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is tagged [vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net), so the syntax highlighter assumes that your code is VB.NET (not C#), so it does not treat those comments as comments and highlights the keywords that are in them.

Comment: Thanks.. I guess in my head I see `VB.NET` and `C#` as the same. I did not know the tags affected the highlighter though. Makes sense anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can force a code block to format with a particular language tag by using a language hint.  For example:

```
<!-- language: lang-cs -->
```

Putting that in front of a code block will transform what was hinted to be vb.net

```vb
public void Next()
{
    // select next, or wrap around after last player
    current=(current+1)%players.Count;
}
```

into

```cs
public void Next()
{
    // select next, or wrap around after last player
    current=(current+1)%players.Count;
}
```

Without this, the syntax picker will chose the language the question is tagged with (in this case it was vb.net)

This is particularly useful when you want to have multiple languages in a single post as each code block can be hinted differently.

See also: [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184108/213963)